# MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm currently new to `Hibernate` and trying to figure out how to use `@Inheritance` annotation for mapping hierarchical entities.

Here's my `BaseEntity`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<ID> {

@Id
private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I have a `User` entity as below:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "user_type",
    discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Table(name = "user")

public class User extends BaseEntity<Long> {

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "username",
        unique = true)
private String userName;

@Column(name = "password")
private String passWord;

@Column(name = "user_type")
private Integer userType;

}
```

..and a `Commander` which is a user as well:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
public class Commander extends User{


}
```

When the application wants to create the tables I get `MappingException`:

```
 MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: model.Commander column: 
 user_type (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the definition of `@Column(name = "user_type")` to `@Column(name="user_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)`?

Comment: That actually helped thanks. But could you please explain why I had to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You are unwittingly or consciously trying to create another `user_type` field while being used for `@DiscriminatorValue`.

**You change `user_type` column to read-only mode (i.e. `insertable = false, updatable = false`)**, hibernate knows what values should it use for insert/update as there is only single source of truth.

```java
@Column(name="user_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer userType;
```